# PHP SQL update query with form

Tags: php, date, unix, datetime, iso8601

```
    <section id="media" class="four">
                <div class="container">
                    <header>  <h2>Media</h2>   </header>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST["mediaOpslaan"])) {
                        header("Location: #media");
                        //SQL update query
                        $sqlInsert = 'UPDATE Media SET Album1=:album1, Album2=:album2, Album3=:album3, WHERE ID=:id';
                        $preparedStatement = $dbh->prepare($sqlInsert);
                        $preparedStatement->execute(array(
                            'id' => 1,
                            'album1' => $_POST["album1"],
                            'album2' => $_POST["album2"],
                            'album3' => $_POST["album3"]
                        ));
                    }
                    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Media WHERE ID =:nummer");
                    $bindings = array(
                        "nummer" => 1
                    );
                    $sth->execute($bindings);
                    $media = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>  Album 1:          </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="<?= $media["Album1"] ?>" name="album1">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>  <td> Album 2:      </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="<?= $media["Album2"] ?>" name="album2">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>     Album 3:   </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" value="<?= $media["Album3"] ?>" name="album3">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan='2'>
                                    <button type="submit" name="mediaOpslaan">Opslaan</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

The connection is correct, this code uses a form to update a row in the database, the same code works with other tables in my database, but not this one? :(

here is a screenshot from my DB: 
http://s2.postimg.org/jpwhe91ax/Capture.png

Thanks so much in advance, i have been looking at it over and over, but cant seem to find the problem.

Comment: `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` would have told you about the (off-topic) syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos:

```
 $sqlInsert = 'UPDATE Media SET ...snip... =:album3, WHERE ID=:id
                                                   ^--- stray comma
```

Since you haven't mentioned any errors/exceptions, you're probably running PDO in default "return false" mode, which means you **HAVE** to check for errors yourself:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(...) or die($dbh->errorInfo());
```